# I somehow lost the admin role of my own Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

For some unknown reason, my Facebook Page has no Admin. I created the Page myself and have even assigned 2 Editors, but when I checked the page roles last month, I noticed that my status has changed from Admin to Editor. Now we are 3 Editors and no Admin.

Please do note that I did not accidently demote myself as Facebook does not permit that when you are the sole admin. I also did not promote someone else to Admin and got myself demoted that way, because even if that did happen there would still be at least 1 Admin left.

If you check the attached image below you'll see that there are in fact no Admin on my Page, which means this **has** to be a bug?

Any suggestions on what I should do?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Follow this path. Options > Report a Problem. Use as many details as you need.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From my experience running a page, if you have more than one page admin, you the page creator can be removed by the new admin, vice versa.

This was some time ago and things may be different.
But [their help page](https://www.facebook.com/help/289207354498410) gives the impression it's still the same.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly recommended to ask Facebook support (https://www.facebook.com/help). If it is a real issue by Facebook they will investigate and solve.

Comment: Can you explain how to do this? Details like form URLs or help pages will make your answer more useful.

Comment: Checked the help page, does not help as there are no way to contact them. Nor is my issue listed.